# Permalinks change when edit published post on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

i have created custom post type in my blog but when i trying to update my published post some time it create this issue 
`www.example.com/news/create-new-blog`
after update post
`www.example.com/news/create-new-blog-2`
 my custom post type code

```
function awasome_custom_post_type(){

    $labels= array(
     'name'=> 'news',
     'singular_name'=> 'news',
     'add_new' => 'Add New news',
     'all_items'=> 'All Items',
     'add_new_items'=> 'Add Item',
     'edit_items'=> 'Edit item',
     'new_items'=> 'New Item',
     'view_item'=> 'View Item',
     'search_item'=> 'search Guide',
     'not_found'=> 'No item found',
     'not_found_in_trash'=> 'No Item Found In Trash',
     'parent_item_colon'=> 'Parent Item'
    );
    $args=array(
    'labels'=> $labels,
    'public'=> true,
    'has_archive'=> true,
    'publicly_queryable'=> true,
    'query_var'=> true,
    'rewrite'=> true,
    'capability_type'=> 'post',
    'hierarchical'=> true,
    'supports'=> array(
    'title',
    'editor',
    'excerpt',
    'thumbnail',
    'revisions',
    'comments' ),
    'taxonomies'=> array('category', 'post_tag'),
    'menu_position'=> 5,
    'exclode_from_search'=> false
    );
    register_post_type('news',$args);
 }
 add_action('init','awasome_custom_post_type');
```

Comment: Likely impossible to tell from just registration code, especially if it doesn't happen consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your register post type with the following, it have few changes like, you have 
`exclode_from_search` 
replace it with 
`exclude_from_search` 
and I have included items that are basics in `$args`. This might create page not found if you are inside a post, go to dashboard and reclick in `News` post type

```
function awasome_custom_post_type() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                  => _x( 'News', 'News General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'         => _x( 'News', 'News Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'             => __( 'News', 'text_domain' ),
    'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'News', 'text_domain' ),
    'archives'              => __( 'News Archives', 'text_domain' ),
    'attributes'            => __( 'News Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent News:', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'             => __( 'All News', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New News', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item'              => __( 'New News', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit News', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'           => __( 'Update News', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'             => __( 'View News', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_items'            => __( 'View News', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'          => __( 'Search News', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
    'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
    'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into News', 'text_domain' ),
    'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this News', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list'            => __( 'News list', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list_navigation' => __( 'News list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
    'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter News list', 'text_domain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label'                 => __( 'News', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'           => __( 'News Description', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'comments' ),
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    'menu_position'         => 5,
    'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'taxonomies'=> array('category', 'post_tag'),
    'can_export'            => true,
    'has_archive'           => true,        
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'capability_type'       => 'post',
);
register_post_type( 'news', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'awasome_custom_post_type', 0 );
```